# Как сделать вывод в tkinter python 3,чтобы текст выводился прямо под кнопкой,а не в самом python,желательно с линией между ними

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как сделать вывод в tkinter python 3,чтобы текст выводился прямо под кнопкой,а не в самом python,желательно с линией между ними.

```
from random import choice
from tkinter import *

sy = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K","L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T" ,"U", "V","W", "X", "Y","Z",
                "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k","l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t" ,"u", "v","w", "x", "y","z",
                "1" , "2","3" ,"4" ,"5" ,"6" ,"7","8" ,"9" ,"0","."]

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Password Generator")
root.geometry("400x300")

def Generate(event):
    print(''.join(choice(sy) for i in range(10)))


btn = Button(root,
             text="Generate",
             width=20,height=2,
             bg="grey",fg="black",
             font='arial 19')
btn.bind("<Button-1>", Generate)
btn.pack()
btn.pack(side='top')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В функции `generate` обращаться к виджету (Label, например) и ему указывать текст

Comment: вы хотите всё в одну строчку выводить (заменяя предыдущий вывод) и многострочный вывод с полосами прокрутки хотите?

Comment: @jfs многострочный вывод с полосами прокрутки желательно бы

Answer (score 2):

Для показа многострочного текста с полосой прокрутки, можно [`ScrolledText`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import secrets
import string
from tkinter import BOTH, END, HORIZONTAL, Tk, scrolledtext, ttk


def generate_password(size=40,
                      alphabet=string.ascii_letters + string.digits+".",
                      choice=secrets.choice):
    return ''.join([choice(alphabet) for _ in range(size)])


def show_new_password():
    console.configure(state='normal')  # enable insert
    console.insert(END, generate_password() + '\n')
    console.yview(END)  # autoscroll
    console.configure(state='disabled')  # disable editing


root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Password Generator")
root.geometry("400x300")
ttk.Button(root, text='Generate', command=show_new_password).pack()
ttk.Separator(root, orient=HORIZONTAL).pack(fill=BOTH)  # line in-between
console = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, state='disable')
console.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: scrolledtext under button screencast]

Comment: конечно это скорее всего будет выглядеть как отдельный вопрос, но в чем разница между `choice` от импортирования `random` чем `choice` от импортирования от `secrets` ?

Comment: @Twiss приоритеты разные у модулей. secrets модуль на безопасности акцент делает (сложнее предсказать какой пароль). random может принять во внимание: воспроизводимость (тестирование), производительность. [PEP-506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте после кнопки `Text` и добавляйте информацию после нажатия на кнопку

Пример:

```
from random import choice
from tkinter import *
import string


def generate(event):
    tex.config(state=NORMAL)
    tex.insert(END, ''.join(choice(sy) for i in range(10)) + '\n')
    tex.config(state=DISABLED)


sy = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Password Generator")
root.geometry("400x300")

btn = Button(root,
             text="Generate",
             width=20, height=2,
             bg="grey", fg="black",
             font='arial 19')
btn.bind("<Button-1>", generate)
btn.pack(side='top')

tex = Text(root, state=DISABLED)
scr = Scrollbar(root, command=tex.yview)
tex.configure(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
scr.pack(side='right', fill='y')
tex.pack(fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```